# Is this a reasonable use of hook_user_presave?

Tags: hooks, users

The [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) for `hook_user_presave` says that

> This hook is primarily intended for modules that want to store properties in the serialized {users}.data column [...]

Instead, I'm using it to check that a change of email address does not clash with any email address in a database separate from the database for my drupal site. If it does, I do

```
$edit['mail'] = $account->mail;
```

so that the update to `mail` does not go through, but the rest of the edit is unaffected. (I also put up a warning message, under the assumption that the only time the email changes is when someone changes it manually.)

With anything web-related being outside my usual field, I'm not sure if using this method in a different way than intended is too clumsy or unsafe. Is it ok to use this method in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation page for Drupal 8, you will notice that sentence is not used anymore.

> Act on a user account being inserted or updated.
>
> This hook is invoked before the user account is saved to the database.
>
> Modules that want to store properties in the serialized {users}.data column, which is automatically loaded whenever a user account object is loaded, may add their properties to $account->data in order to have their data serialized on save.

The fact the hook has different parameters in Drupal 8 doesn't change its purpose. In fact, with Drupal 8 you could use the following code.

```
$account->mail = $account->original->mail;
```

`$account->original` contains the value returned from [entity_load_unchanged()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!entity!entity.module/function/entity_load_unchanged/8).

Although on Drupal `hook_user_presave()` is normally used for the purpose you noticed, you could use it for the purpose you described.

The alternative would be to add a form submission handler to the user edit form which is executed before the default form submission handler. The pro of using `hook_user_presave()` is that it works also when a module programmatically save a user object using `user_save()`.

Comment: I notice that the Drupal 8 version has different parameters, and doesn't look like it can be treated the same way I'm treating this version. I.e. `$edit` and `$account` as being separate and different from one another.

Comment: The different arguments accepted from the hook don't change its purpose. What you are trying to achieve can be achieved also with Drupal 8; see the updated answer.

Comment: Obviously, I need to learn to navigate the documentation better. :)